# Two similar Spring endpoints, wrong one is being called

Tags: spring-boot

I have two endpoints in the same controller file

```
    @PostMapping("{app}/{schema}")
    public ResponseEntity createResource(
                               @PathVariable final String app,
                               @PathVariable final String schema,
                               @RequestBody final Object input,
                               final HttpServletRequest request) {
    //do stuff

}

@PostMapping("{app}/bulk")
public ResponseEntity bulk(
                           @PathVariable final String app,
                           @RequestBody final Object input,
                           final HttpServletRequest request) {
//do stuff
  }
```

The createResource gets called when I do POST app/bulk.

Answer (score 1):

Your first endpoint

```
@PostMapping("{app}/{schema}")
```

is a wildcard endpoint due to two `PathVariables`. Therefor, any request to a path `yourapp.com/xyz` is caught by it and the second endpoint is always ignored.

To solve this, you should either create two distinct endpoints without using the `{schema}` `PathVariable` like you are doing in the second endpoint, or just use the first one as is and check the `{schema}` variable for the current path in `//do stuff`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when the URL gets resolve, your first endpoint will perfectly fit in.

@PostMapping("{app}/{schema}")

Here bulk will be resolve as {schema} string. You can avoid it by defining a unique name like this :

@PostMapping("{app}/schema/{schema}")

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately as these APIs are for an open standard , they are the exact endpoint names I must use

Answer (score 0):

You should merge two endpoint like this

```
@PostMapping("{app}/{schema}")
public ResponseEntity createResource(
        @PathVariable final String app,
        @PathVariable final String schema,
        @RequestBody final Object input,
        final HttpServletRequest request) {

    if ("bulk".equals(schema)) {
        // do bulk stuff
    } else {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```